# How to use Enter key instead of NextButton on Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

On Qualtrics I would like to hide the NextButton and use the enter key instead:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()  {
$('NextButton').hide();         
document.on("keydown", function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode === 13) $('NextButton').click();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change addOnload to addOnReady.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18703736)

Comment: It most certainly does provide an answer. It tells the OP how to fix the code  posted so it will work.